# wordpress site work on local but not works on online server error http error 500

Tags: wordpress

my WordPress site correctly working on local server but when I'm uploading it on server `do_action( 'init' )` in wp-settings.php breaks my website.

I debug and see an error in `do_action( 'init' )` line 393 in file wp-settings.

Comment: well what do you have on line 393, in your file?

Answer (score 0):

please include the error messege and some details about theme, WP version and active plugins.

I think that it probably occures from some service (cron, ram) related to your hosting company or some plugin/theme having some serious error.

check this link for possible answers: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110074/do-action-init-in-wp-settings-php-breaks-my-website-all-plugins-and-themes